# Android Studio app crashes when i try to test it

Tags: java, android-studio, android-emulator, android-fragmentactivity

The app crashes when i tried to test, i am using fragments to create the app:
[App crashed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zvKp.png)
I have this in audioFragment.java:

```
package amaguenet.com.reproductorxassidas;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class audioFragment extends Fragment {
    // variable declaration
    private ListView mainList;
    private MediaPlayer mp;
    private final String[] listContent = {"Ahonzubilahi Min Mayli", "Ajabani Khayru Baqin", "Ajabani Rabbu Sama", "Ala Innani Usni",
            "Alal Muntaqa Khayril Baraya"};

    private final int[] resID = {R.raw.ahonzu_bilahi_min_mayli, R.raw.ajabani_khayru_baqin, R.raw.ajabani_rabbu_sama,
            R.raw.ala_innani_usni, R.raw.alal_muntaqa_khayril_baraya};

    @Override
    public View  onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_audio, container, false);
// Initializing variables
        mp = new MediaPlayer();
        mainList = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listContent);
        mainList.setAdapter(adapter);

        mainList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                playSong(position);

            }
        });
        return v;
}

    public void playSong(int songIndex) {
// Play song
        mp.reset();// stops any current playing song
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), resID[songIndex]);// create's
// new
// mediaplayer
// with
// song.

        mp.start(); // starting mediaplayer

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mp.release();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
// Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
// Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
// automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
// as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    }
}
```

And this in a in fragment_audio (the layout):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="amaguenet.com.reproductorxassidas.audioFragment"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" >
        </ListView>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Can some helps with this, i am using Fragments in Android Studio?

Answer (score 0):

You can use getIdentifier() method, here is a simple example:

```
    private final int resID = getContext().getResources().getIdentifier(direction, "raw", PACKAGE_NAME);
```

direction - string with your file name f.e: "ahonzu_bilahi_min_mayli"

PACKAGE_NAME - is  your package name

Comment: Hello, with the rebuild, now the app is opened but if i click on one of the 2 last items the app crashes again. Any help